# INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER for a table with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I get this error:

> Cannot create INSTEAD OF DELETE or INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER 'trig_Income_Updater' on table 'MYBUDGET.tbl_Income'. This is because the table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE.

I can use 'FOR UPDATE'. but how to make it to ignore the original update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the fields you want and then "undo" the original update using the "inserted" and "deleted" temporary tables that are provided to the trigger.

For example (untested):

```
--Do the stuff you want
UPDATE table SET fields = values WHERE some condition


--Undo the original update (minus anything you WANT changed above)
UPDATE table SET unchangingfield = deleted.unchangingfield WHERE ID = deleted.ID
```

The "inserted" table will contain the new values, and the "deleted" table contains the values that are being changed.  You can join, query and otherwise treat them as though they were actual tables.

Answer (score 2):

To ignore the origional update you will need to utilize a RAISERROR and then ROLLBACK.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) is an example under the "Using a DML AFTER trigger to enforce a business rule between the PurchaseOrderHeader and Vendor tables" section

Comment: ROLLBACK will be ignore all the things i have done in the trigger before execute the ROLLBACK statement. what I need is to ignore only the original update statement.